# How to compute AUC in gridsearchSV (multiclass problem)

Tags: scikit-learn, multiclass-classification, gridsearchcv, scoring, auc

I'm working on a multiclass classification problem, comparing results from SVM and Random Forest classificators. I would like to use gridsearchCV for hyperparameters tuning and find that AUC is the most used metrics for this kind of problem.

I know how to use other metrics of scoring like accuracy etc. but the default ROC_AUC only works for binary class. Is there a method to use AUC in gridsearchCV for multiclass problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sklearn's [`roc_auc_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html) actually does handle multiclass and multilabel problems, with its `average` and `multiclass` parameters.  The default `average='macro'` is fine, though you should consider the alternative(s).  But the default `multiclass='raise'` will need to be overridden.  To use that in a `GridSearchCV`, you can curry the function, e.g.

```
import functools

multiclass_roc_auc = functools.partial(roc_auc_score, multiclass='ovr')
search = GridSearchCV(estimator=...,
                      eval=multiclass_roc_auc,
                      ...)
```

Comment: I fixed my problem by defining my multiclass_roc_auc function. Your solution is very helpful and slightly shorter, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There are actually several flavors of [AUC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.get_scorer_names.html#sklearn.metrics.get_scorer_names) you can now use with multiclass evaluation:

- 'roc_auc_ovo'
- 'roc_auc_ovo_weighted'
- 'roc_auc_ovr'
- 'roc_auc_ovr_weighted'

These also work with `BayesSearchCV` from `skopt` and do not require creating your own scorer with `functools.partial`

Answer (score 1):

Metrics are independent from ML algorithms, so it **doesn't matter** which algorithms did you use.

To calculate **multiclass AUC** you could use lib pRoc in **R** or use code this [link](https://medium.com/@plog397/auc-roc-curve-scoring-function-for-multi-class-classification-9822871a6659)(in Python).

Sources:

- https://web.expasy.org/pROC/
- https://medium.com/@plog397/auc-roc-curve-scoring-function-for-multi-class-classification-9822871a6659

Comment: I mean the evaluation metrics that the GridsearchCV function uses to find best params